# Require domain name and DNS should resolve proper host names on windows 2012

Tags: fqdn

I have installed Siebel ip2017 on Google cloud free tier environment for self study however it is failing in configuration as it require FQDN( Require domain name and DNS should resolve proper host names).
Currently it has shortname without domain name and its failing in prerequisites.
Please help how I can get fully qualified domain name(free tier) to cope configuration relate issue.

Thanking in anticipation.

Regards,
Ganesh

Comment: You can buy a domain name from many registrars if you don't already have one.

Comment: Is there any freeware for domain name just for POC purpose.